# When making an ajax request, how can I use a jquery variable in the url parameter that uses c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is the code that I have:

```
var selectedFacility = $("#Facility").val();

$.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetLocations", "Item", new { Facility = "selectedFacility goes here"})",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#Location').append('<option value="' + data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Text + '</option > ');
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller action:

```
public JsonResult GetLocations(string facility) {
        var Locations = new List<SelectListItem>{};
        Locations.AddRange(db.Locations.Where(l => l.Facility == "LAT").ToList().Select(l => new SelectListItem {
            Text = l.Name,
            Value = l.ID.ToString()
        }));
        return Json(Locations, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is the line that I need to use the variable on:

```
new { Facility = "selectedFacility goes here"})",
```

I might be missing something obvious, but I need to use the `selectedFacility` jquery variable in the Url.Action() parameters.  Is there a way that  this can be done?

Comment: can u show your GetLocations method code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't use `$("#Facility").val();` parameter in the `Url.Action()` method.

You are using http `POST` I think you can try to set the `ajax` data object to be the parameter.

```
var selectedFacility = $("#Facility").val();

$.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetLocations", "Item")',
        data: { Facility: selectedFacility },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#Location').append('<option value="' + data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Text + '</option > ');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this solution works.  I just tried it but I get a syntax error.

Comment: @sjohn285 try 'data: { facility: selectedFacility }'